# contact form 7 3.5.2 not sending email fter upgrading wordpress 3.6

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am working on word press theme but when i upgrade Contact form 7 in to 3.5.2 and WP into 3.6 contact 7 it stops sending emails.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

kindly check contact form 7 settings(email part) in dashboard...bcoz while upgrading to version 6 database also get upgraded.Due to that setting u made previously will get erased...so make that setting again...